# how do you sort time zones please?

Tags: .net, timezone

Hi I'm using the following to populate a drop down list.  I would prefer the list was sorted alphabetically on ID rather than the default.

ReadOnlyCollection zones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().OrderBy(??);

Im struggling with the Orderby syntax - what needs to go in here please?

Comment: "I would prefer the list was sorted alphabetically" - alphabetically by what? Display name? ID? Once you've answered that, that's what goes in your `OrderBy` call...

Comment: (I'd also strongly discourage this as an approach. If you don't happen to know what the Windows Time Zone Database calls your time zone, it could be really hard to find it. If you order by (say) standard offset, then it's easy for users to find the *rough* set to check through.)

Comment: Agree with Jon.  The list coming back from `GetSystemTimeZones` is already in the preferred sorting order.

Comment: I was hoping to sort by ID to make it easier for web user to find their zone.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> I was hoping to sort by ID to make it easier for web user to find their zone.

If you *really* wanted to do that, it would be like this:

```
var zones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().OrderBy(zone => zone.Id);
```

However, I *strongly* suggest that you don't do that.  The list returned by `GetSystemTimeZones` is already sorted in an order that is convenient for the user to find their zone, as long as you are presenting the list properly.

If you are showing them the `Id` property, then that might be the source of the confusion.  You should not.  Instead, show them the `DisplayName` property, and then save the corresponding `Id`.

For example, if you are creating an HTML `<select>` list, each `<option>` tag should have the `Id` put in the `value` attribute, and the `DisplayName` put in the option element's body.